# NameError at /system/invn/create name 'name' is not defined modelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I trying to create a form with `ModelForm` that save it to a database. But got an error.

here my models.py

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sn = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default='Tidak ada deskripsi')
```

here my `forms.py`

```
class InventoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    sn = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
    desc = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = ('name', 'sn', 'desc',)
```

here my `views.py`

```
class InventoryCreateView(TemplateView):
    template_name ='system/inventory_form.html'
    def get(self, request):
        form = InventoryForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = InventoryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        args = {'form': form, 'name': name, 'sn': sn, 'desc': desc}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

its said `NameError at /system/invn/create name 'name' is not defined modelForm` from `args = {'form': form, 'name': name, 'sn': sn, 'desc': desc}`

what missed here?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to fetch the `name` field from your `modelform` directly from your `post` method.

Your `post` method has no variable named `name`. Note that you are passing your `form` as an arg already, which can be used in your `template`.

in your template you can use those values from your `form` arg that you passed as context. Though, if you really specifically want to pass them in your `args` as context, you can pass them from your `form.cleaned_data` since it is validated in `is_valid()` like:

```
def post(self, request):
    form = InventoryForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    args = {
        'form': form, 
        'name': form.cleaned_data.get('name'), 
        'sn': form.cleaned_data.get('sn'), 
        'desc': form.cleaned_data.get('desc')
   }
   return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

+1 on Ashish Acharya's answer:

> ...though this will fail when the form is not valid. So, you might need to add some code to handle that condition.

Comment: ah, thanks. I thought because `'form': form,` name also `'name': name`. but its wrong.

Comment: No, you did define `form` as  `form = InventoryForm(request.POST)` but in the same function you never defined `name`, `sn`, and `desc`. Those only live within your `form`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the line causing the error:

```
args = {'form': form, 'name': name, 'sn': sn, 'desc': desc}
```

`name`, `sn`, and `desc` are not defined here.

So, you need to grab the saved object and access its attributes:

```
if form.is_valid():
    inventory = form.save()

args = {'form': form, 'name': inventory.name, 'sn': inventory.sn, 'desc': inventory.desc}
```

...though this will fail when the form is not valid. So, you might need to  add some code to handle that condition.

Comment: I don't quite get your question.